# PHP switch statement always taking default

Tags: php, html, forms, switch-statement

I am following some php examples from a book, and working through them. The code below is suppose to validate whether the file type uploaded matches on of the set valid types using a switch statement. Valid types are: jpeg, png, tiff and gif. However, the code always seems to take the default statement and break out of the loop. I have even downloaded the example from the website, and the same problem is occurring!

```
echo <<<_END
<html><head><tile>PHP Form Upload</title></head>
<body>
<form method='post' action='upload2.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select a JPG, GIF, PNG or TIF File: 
<input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' /></form>
_END;

if ($_FILES)
{
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

switch ($_FILES['filename']['type'])
{
    case 'image/jpeg':  $ext = 'jpg';   break;
    case 'image/gif':   $ext = 'gif';   break;
    case 'image/png':   $ext = 'png';   break;
    case 'image/tiff':  $ext = 'tiff';  break;
    default:            $ext = '';      break;
}

if ($ext){

    $n = "image.$ext";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['filename']['tmp_name'],$n);
    echo "Uploaded image '$name' as '$n':<br />";
    echo "<img src='$n'";
}
else echo "'$name' is not a valid image file";
 }
 else echo "No image has been uploaded";

 echo "</body></html>"


 ?>
```

If i say upload the image 'image.jpg', it should set $ext to .$jpg and then perform the upload, but I just get the else statement:

```
else echo "'$name' is not a valid image file";
```

Comment: Have you tied printing `$_FILES['filename']['type']` to see why it's going through the wrong path?

Comment: I haven't yet, will do that shortly. I tried placing some simple echo statments, which didn't really help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example doesn't work because the file mime type isn't in your case statements.

Modify the code so you can check the mime type of the file :

```
else echo "'$name' is not a valid image file (".$_FILES['filename']['type']." unallowed)";
```

Then if you want to add this mime type you can modify your switch / case statement accordingly using the type shown with this modification.

EDIT :

note that you can also use `var_dump()` php function to check the content of a variable.

```
else{
    echo "'$name' is not a valid image file (".$_FILES['filename']['type']." unallowed)";
    var_dump($_FILES['filename']);
}
```

EDIT :

Remember to always sanitize client data before serving it (htmlentities() does the trick), check http://fr.php.net/htmlentities :

```
echo "'$name' is not a valid image file (".htmlentities($_FILES['filename']['type'])." unallowed)";
```